# ASP.NET session terminates before session timeout

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session

We have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application running on IIS 7.0 in a load balanced environment. After the web page initially loads, we are refreshing some sections of the web page after every 5 mins using AJAX UpdatePanel and web services.

The website is expected to run continuously without any user intervention for more than 12 hours and up to 2 days. The session timeout has been set to the maximum value, 525600. The App Pool also has been configured not to recycle. The executionTimeout is also configured with a higher value.

However, the application has been failing intermittently. On refreshing the web page, it redirects to the WSSO login page indicating that the session has terminated. We couldn't find any error traces on the web server logs. The session mode is inproc.

Please let me know if I am missing anything. Any guidance would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: are you using `inproc` session mode?

Comment: Can you please provide session mode at your end, that will helps us in trouble shoot further at our sandbox.

Comment: Yes, the Session mode is inproc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In load balanced environment, you cannot use InProc for Session-State.

Instead, you need to use either StateServer or SQLServer.

[Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

### Other Thoughts

- If you use **FormAuthentication**, its timeout must be **at least two times greater than** Session Timeout.
- **Machine Key** must be same for all instances.

***FYI:*** Please test in a single web server first. If works, then turn on the load balancing.

Comment: I have modified the session mode to use SQLServer for session storage. However on testing the website for a while, I ended up getting the same session timeout error.

Comment: Thanks, I missed adding the machine key in the config file. It is working fine now. Thanks again for your prompt answers.